# Flutter : How to update text in Button when click

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to change the text inside `ElevatedButton` when I click. For example '`Fav`' to '`Unfav`' and the color of the button when I do this action change also. I tried with boolean and also to change the text in Button inside `setState` block, it didn't help.

[Demontration what I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7tMl.gif)

**Code where I try to do this**

```
ElevatedButton(
    child: Text(title),
    onPressed: () async {

      String ref = ads.reference.id;
      String? favuid = user != null
          ? user?.uid
          : googleUser?.id;

      if (favuid != null) {
        setState(() {
          title = 'UnFav';
          if ((ads.data() as dynamic)['isfav$favuid'] == null || !(ads.data() as dynamic)['isfav$favuid']) {
            collectionads.doc(ref).update({
              'isfav$favuid': true

            });
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              content: Text("Add to Favourite list"),
            ));
          }
          else {
            title = 'Fav';
            collectionads.doc(ref).update({
              'isfav$favuid': false
            });
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              content: Text(
                  "Deleted from Favourite list"),
            ));

          }
        });
        setState(() {
          !(ads.data() as dynamic)['isfav$favuid'] == (ads.data() as dynamic)['isfav$favuid'];
        });
      }
    },
    
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `title` variable needs to be a part of a `StatefulWidget`'s state class, and `setState` will then change the text

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String title = 'Fav';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          title = 'UnFav';
        });
      }, child: Text(title))
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  bool fav = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if(fav)
              setState(() => fav=false);
            else
              setState(() => fav=true);
          },
          child: Text(fav ? 'Fav' : 'Unfav'),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: fav? Colors.blue : Colors.black12,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking part of my question! Your all suggestion works, so i will choose correct answer who is have smallest reputation score)

Comment: No problem, if its work you are invited for vote

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a combination of **single bool variable** and `setState` to set the button state from `isFav` to `!isFav`.
Now you can change anything inside your method `setState` similarly as we changed **text** and **color**.

@anderson48 Try the code below it this way its easiest to achieve what you want to,
try to run this code in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isFav = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold( appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text("Sample"),
        ),
    body: Column(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    isFav
        ? MaterialButton(
            child: Text("button 1" , style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 32)), // fav
            onPressed: () {
               setState(() {
     isFav = !isFav;
            });
            },
          )
        : Container(),
    !(isFav)
        ? MaterialButton(
            child: Text("Button 2" , style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontSize: 50)),  // not fav
            onPressed: () {
               setState(() {
     isFav = !isFav;
            });
            },
          )
        : Container(),
  ],
)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking part of my question! Your all suggestion works, so i will choose correct answer who is have smallest reputation score)

Comment: @anderson48 np but if you do want to help me you can jut upvote my answer, it would mean a lot to me...

Comment: well it seems your are new to Stackoverflow there is difference in accepting answer and upvoting question. You upvote the answer by clicking on up button next to the answer if you find the post helpful it helps people gain trust over the person and makes easy for other developers to check which answer is more useful by votes and accepted answer.... no worries

Answer (score 0):

setState() will not work inside build() in flutter new releases.

Describe function in class and you can write all code in this function.

```
    void yourFunction(){
      setState(() {
       isFav = !isFav;
       });
    }
```

and  After

```
onPressed: yourFunction,
```

Comment: Thanks for taking part of my question! Your all suggestion works, so i will choose correct answer who is have smallest reputation score)